# mysql trigger if not update

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estou com uma dúvida ao criar uma trigger, preciso que ela só seja executada se não foi atualizado o campo: integraProduto, se qualquer outro campo for atualizado ela deverá ser executada.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `cadastro`.`trgProdutos` AFTER UPDATE
    ON `cadastro`.Produtos
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     IF NOT UPDATE(integraProduto) THEN
    SET NEW.integraProduto=1;
     END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

erro:
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE(integraProduto) THEN
    SET NEW.integraProduto=1;
     END IF;

Comment: não existe html, pois o problema é na trigger do mysql, minha dúvida é como criar uma trigger com essa condição: IF NOT UPDATE(integraProduto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER `cadastro`.`trgProdutos` BEFORE UPDATE ON `cadastro`.Produtos FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
   IF (new.integraProduto = old.integraProduto) THEN
      SET NEW.integraProduto=1;
   END IF;
END$

DELIMITER ;
```